# Sharing secret across namespaces

Tags: namespaces, kubernetes

Is there a way to share secrets across namespaces in Kubernetes?

My use case is: I have the same private registry for all my namespaces and I want to avoid creating the same secret for each.

Comment: this automates the secret sharing:  https://github.com/zakkg3/ClusterSecret

Comment: You can access secrets from a different namespace with proper RBAC permissions. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73418121/how-allow-pod-from-default-namespace-read-secret-from-other-namespace/73419051#73419051

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Secret API objects reside in a namespace. They can only be referenced by pods in that same namespace. Basically, you will have to create the secret for every namespace.

For more details, see this: [Kubernetes Documentation / Concepts / Configuration / Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#details)

Comment: Same for configmaps. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#restrictions

Comment: That's the correct answer, worth mention you can clone to another namespace by kubectl + sed, all in one line, see my answer below.

Comment: @NicoKowe copying the secrets with kubectl and some shell magic is possible, but this gets exciting (the opposite of boring) if you want to update the secret.

Comment: @guettli yes, in that case i recommend to go with the ClusterSecret operator.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? Most other answers provide solutions that solve the OP's problem, IMO.

Answer (score 161):

They can only be referenced by pods in that same namespace. But you can just copy secret from one name space to other. Here is a example of copying `localdockerreg` secret from `default` namespace to `dev`:

```
kubectl get secret localdockerreg --namespace=default --export -o yaml | kubectl apply --namespace=dev -f -
```

###UPDATE###
In Kubernetes v1.14 `--export` flag is [deprecated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/73787). So, the following Command with `-oyaml` flag will work without a warning in forthcoming versions.

```
kubectl get secret localdockerreg --namespace=default -oyaml | kubectl apply --namespace=dev -f -
```

or below if source namespace is not necessarily default

```sh
kubectl get secret localdockerreg --namespace=default -oyaml | grep -v '^\s*namespace:\s' | kubectl apply --namespace=dev -f -
```

Comment: This will not work if secrets that you are exporting from are not in the default namespace

Comment: Works for me across any two namespaces on v1.13

Comment: Hmm when I use the second command (no `--export` flag) I get an error saying "the namespace from the provided option does not match". kubectl version 1.15. I think you may need to use `sed` or something in between those two `kubectl` commands to remove the namespace from the output yaml

Comment: To be precise, you need to remove the source namespace from the intermediate YAML:
`$ kubectl get secret <SECRET> --namespace <NS-SRC> -oyaml | grep -v '^\s*namespace:\s' | kubectl apply --namespace <NS-DST> -f -`

p.s. not tested with other object types, but should work

p.p.s. don't forget to delete source if you're moving

Comment: works, and change context with kubectl use context if between clusters

Answer (score 65):

The accepted answer is correct: Secrets can only be referenced by pods in that same namespace. So here is a hint if you are looking to automate the "sync" or just copy the secret between namespaces.

### Automated (operator)

For automating the share or syncing secret across namespaces use ClusterSecret operator:

https://github.com/zakkg3/ClusterSecret

#### Using sed:

```sh
kubectl get secret <secret-name> -n <source-namespace> -o yaml \
| sed s/"namespace: <source-namespace>"/"namespace: <destination-namespace>"/\
| kubectl apply -n <destination-namespace> -f -
```

#### Use jq

If you have jq, we can use the @Evans Tucker solution

```sh
kubectl get secret cure-for-covid-19 -n china -o json \
 | jq 'del(.metadata["namespace","creationTimestamp","resourceVersion","selfLink","uid"])' \
 | kubectl apply -n rest-of-world -f -
```

Comment: There is some metadata that should be removed when porting secrets, see [Evans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627332/1318694)

Comment: For that you have to install jq, and in some situations that could not be possible. But I added this option too, thanks Matt!

Comment: No worries, I was just trying to highlight the functional difference between the two answers for people who see this one first

Comment: Also my comment should have said "might want to remove" as it can be useful to keep the source metadata too

Answer (score 31):

Secrets are namespaced resources, but you can use a Kubernetes extension to replicate them. We use this to propagate credentials or certificates stored in secrets to all namespaces automatically and keep them in sync (modify the source and all copies are updated).
See Kubernetes Reflector (https://github.com/EmberStack/kubernetes-reflector).

The extension allows you to automatically copy and keep in sync a secret across namespaces via annotations:

On the source secret add the annotations:

```
 annotations:
   reflector.v1.k8s.emberstack.com/reflection-auto-enabled: "true"
```

This will create a copy of the secret in all namespaces. You can limit the namespaces in which a copy is created using:

```
reflector.v1.k8s.emberstack.com/reflection-allowed-namespaces: "namespace-1,namespace-2,namespace-[0-9]*"
```

The extension supports ConfigMaps and cert-manager certificates as well.
Disclainer: I am the author of the Kubernetes Reflector extension.

Answer (score 26):

Here's an example that uses `jq` to delete the namespace and other metadata we don't want:

```
kubectl get secret cure-for-covid-19 -n china -o json \
 | jq 'del(.metadata["namespace","creationTimestamp","resourceVersion","selfLink","uid"])' \
 | kubectl apply -n rest-of-world -f -
```

Note:

- the deprecated `--export` flag is no longer supported in `kubectl`,
- `sed` is not the appropriate tool for editing YAML or JSON.

Comment: This should be the #2 answer right under the first explanation of the use and technicals of namespaces. If you came here looking to copy secrets to a new namespace use this.

Comment: Recently when trying this with a secret, there was also another section to remove: `ownerReferences`. So the new `jq` string looks like
`jq 'del(.metadata["namespace","creationTimestamp","resourceVersion","selfLink","uid", "ownerReferences"])'`

Answer (score 11):

Use RBAC to authorize the serviceaccount to use the secret on the original namespaces. But, this is not recommended to have a shared secret between namesapces.

Comment: This is the **only correct** answer with right warning. See this for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/73419051/6309601

Answer (score 9):

I want to help clear up two misinformation I found on other answers.

## RBAC and ServiceAccount can not be used to share `imagePullSecret` across namespaces.

Sure, RBAC can allow application running in a Pod to read Secret from another namespace using kubernetes API or client libraries. (See minimal working example in bonus section below.)

However, this approach does not work when sharing the Secret to be used in `imagePullSecret` field of Pod specification. The reasons being:

1. The application that use the secret in creation of a Pod is `kubelet` which itself is not running in a Pod and has no associated ServiceAccount.
2. The `imagePullSecret` can only reference Secret within the same namespace. [See the API reference.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#containers)

## Secret can be copied from one namespace to another using just `kubectl`. (No `jq` or `sed` needed.)

The trick is to dry-run application of JSON patch to existing secret to get new Secret document with namespace edited.

```bash
kubectl patch secret \
  -n SOURCE-NAMESPACE SECRET-NAME \
  --type=json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/metadata/namespace", "value": "DESTINATION-NAMESPACE"}]'  \
  -o yaml --dry-run=client |
  kubectl apply -f -
```

---

## Bonus: Minimal Working Example for sharing Secret across namespace and accessing it with kubernetes Python client.

I'm not going to explain the example further, because it does not apply to the kind of Secret OP is talking about. However, I think it will be helpful for those mislead by the RBAC solution like I was.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: secret-owner-namespace
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: secret-reader-namespace
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: example-secret
  namespace: secret-owner-namespace
type: Opaque
data:
  # echo -n secret-value | base64
  SECRET_KEY: c2VjcmV0LXZhbHVl
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: secret-reader-role
  # NOTE: Reader's role is defined inside owner's namespace.
  # That is how `resourcesNames` below can be resolved.
  namespace: secret-owner-namespace
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: ["example-secret"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
---
# Allow pods in secret-reader-namespace to read the example-secret by:
# binding the default ServiceAccount of the secret-reader-namespace
# to the Role of secret-reader-role.
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: secret-reader-rolebinding
  namespace: secret-owner-namespace
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  apiGroup: ""
  namespace: secret-reader-namespace
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: secret-reader-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: secret-reading-code-configmap
  namespace: secret-reader-namespace
data:
  read-secret.py: |
    from kubernetes import client, config

    config.load_incluster_config()
    with client.ApiClient() as api_client:
        api_instance = client.CoreV1Api(api_client)
        name = 'example-secret'
        namespace = 'secret-owner-namespace'
        api_response = api_instance.read_namespaced_secret(name, namespace)

    print(api_response)
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: secret-reader-deployment
  namespace: secret-reader-namespace
  labels:
    app: secret-reader-example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: secret-reader-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: secret-reader-example
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: secret-reading-container 
        image: python
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args: ["pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade kubernetes ; python read-secret.py ; sleep infinity"]
        workingDir: /opt/code
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-reading-code-volume
          mountPath: "/opt/code"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: secret-reading-code-volume
        configMap:
          name: secret-reading-code-configmap
```

Answer (score 8):

[Another option would be to use kubed](https://cert-manager.io/docs/faq/kubed/), one of many recommended options from the kind folks at Jetstack who gave us cert-manager. [Here is what they link to.](https://appscode.com/products/kubed/v0.11.0/guides/config-syncer/intra-cluster/)

Comment: They did not recommend `kubed` particularly, but rather they mention it among 3 recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

Improving from [@NicoKowe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5521600/nicokowe)

One liner to copy all secrets from one namespace to another

```
$ for i in `kubectl get secrets | awk '{print $1}'`; do  kubectl get secret $1 -n <source-namespace> -o yaml | sed s/"namespace: <source-namespace>"/"namespace: <target-namespace>"/ | kubectl apply -n <target-namespace> -f -  ; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Evans Tucker's answer but uses whitelisting rather than deletion within the jq filter to only keep what we want.

`kubectl get secret cure-for-covid-19 -n china -o json | jq '{apiVersion,data,kind,metadata,type} | .metadata |= {"annotations", "name"}' | kubectl apply -n rest-of-world -f -`

Essentially the same thing but preserves labels.

`kubectl get secret cure-for-covid-19 -n china -o json | jq '{apiVersion,data,kind,metadata,type} | .metadata |= {"annotations", "name", "labels"}' | kubectl apply -n rest-of-world -f -`

Answer (score 3):

Well, the question is good, but all the solutions are bad!

Secrets contain sensitive data, as you understand, by design you cant use secret from another namespace. So I dont recommend to use a fancy "cluster scope" operator, that will "push" your secret into namespace "toto-*".

That sounds a bad usage of secret and `kubernetes declarative model`.

### Solution 1: a namespace setup Helm chart

This is the easiest approach, create a **Helm chart to create the namespace and setup it**, by creating resources you want to share.

### Solution 2: use external-secret.io

I love https://external-secrets.io/, this is a **pull declarative approach**. As you can read at https://external-secrets.io/v0.7.2/provider/kubernetes/ , you declare a `ExternalSecret` to pull data from a Secret on another namespace.

external-secrets.io is production ready, battle tested, support some providers (vault ...).

### Solution 3: to share CA

To share CA easily, https://cert-manager.io/docs/projects/trust-manager/. This is a push approach ;-/ but the tool is prod ready.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by Innocent Anigbo, you need to have the secret in the same namespace. If you need to support that dynamicaly or avoid forgeting secret creation, it might be possible to create an initialiser for namespace object https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/extensible-admission-controllers/ (have not done that on my own, so cant tell for sure)

Answer (score 2):

Solution for copying all secrets.

```
kubectl delete secret --namespace $TARGET_NAMESPACE--all;
kubectl get secret --namespace default --output yaml \
    | sed "s/namespace: $SOURCE_NAMESPACE/namespace: $TARGET_NAMESPACE/" \
    | kubectl apply --namespace $TARGET_NAMESPACE --filename -;
```

Comment: It is also a solution to remove all your secrets.

Answer (score 2):

[`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) is a helpful command-line tool for editing YAML files. I utilized this in conjunction with the other answers to get this:

```
kubectl get secret <SECRET> -n <SOURCE_NAMESPACE> -o yaml | yq write - 'metadata.namespace' <TARGET_NAMESPACE> | kubectl apply -n <TARGET_NAMESPACE> -f -
```

Comment: Note that this is for yq < v4. With yq v4 it would look like this:
 `kubectl get secret <SECRET> -n <SOURCE_NAMESPACE> -o yaml | yq eval '.metadata.namespace = "<TARGET_NAMESPACE>"' - | kubectl apply -n <TARGET_NAMESPACE> -f -`

Answer (score 0):

You may also think about using [GoDaddy's Kubernetes External Secrets](https://sg.godaddy.com/engineering/2019/04/16/kubernetes-external-secrets/)! where you will be storing your secrets in AWS Secret Manager(ASM) and GoDaddy's secret controller will create the secrets automatically. Moreover, there would be sync between ASM And K8S cluster.

Comment: But external secrets are also tied to one namespace

Answer (score 0):

For me the method suggested by @Hansika Weerasena didn't work and got the following error:

```
error: the namespace from the provided object "ns_source" does not match the namespace "ns_dest". You must pass '--namespace=ns_source' to perform this operation.
```

To get around this problem I did the the following:

```
kubectl get secret my-secret -n ns_source -o yaml > my-secret.yaml
```

This file **needs to be edited** and the namespace changed to your desired destination namespace. Then simply do:

```
kubectl apply -f my-secret.yaml -n ns_destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Export from one k8s cluster

```
mkdir <namespace>; cd  <namespace>; for i in `kubectl get secrets -n <namespace> | awk '{print $1}'`; do  kubectl get secret $i -n <namespace>  -o yaml > $i.yaml; done
```

Import to Second k8s cluster

```
cd  <namespace>; find . -type f -exec kubectl apply -f '{}' -n  <namespace>  \;
```

Answer (score 0):

With helm, I usually define a (group) variable (e.g. `$REGISTRY_PASS`) in my CD pipeline and add a template file to the helm chart:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: |
    {{ .Values.registryPassword }}
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-registry
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

When deploying the chart, I set the variable `registryPassword` on the command line like so:

```
helm install foo/ --values values.yaml  \
--set registryPassword="$REGISTRY_PASS" \
--namespace whatever \
--create-namespace
```

This is fully compatible with local testing and CD.

To get the correctly formatted value for `$REGISTRY_PASS`, I use `kubectl create secret`

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry secret-tiger-docker \
  --docker-email=tiger@acme.example \
  --docker-username=tiger \
  --docker-password=pass1234 \
  --docker-server=my-registry.example:5000
```

to create the intial secret and then use `kubectl get secret` to get the base64 encoded string (`.dockerconfigjson`).

```
kubectl get secret secret-tiger-docker -o yaml
```

No matter what namespace the application gets installed to, it will always have access to the local registry, since the secret gets installed before the image gets pulled.

Answer (score 0):

Use RBAC to access secrets across namespaces.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

e.g. Uisng a ClusterRole

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: secret-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Secret
  # objects is "secrets"
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Answer (score -1):

kubectl get secret gitlab-registry --namespace=revsys-com --export -o yaml |\
   kubectl apply --namespace=devspectrum-dev -f -